# Service Uploader Missing Argument Exception

Tags: symfony

I created an upload service to use it in different controllers in my code.

But i get an exception now like this when i want to access to the page for add a new gig :

> Controller
>   "Booking\RoosterBundle\Controller\ArtistController::addGigAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$fileUploader" argument.

Why i'm getting this ? the value should be $file but i need to access to my form first and submit the file ... hope someone could help me. thanks a lot in advance

here is my service :

```
<?php


namespace Booking\RoosterBundle\Uploader;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $file->move($this->getTargetDir(), $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDir()
    {
        return $this->targetDir;
    }
}
```

Here my controller :

```
public function addGigAction(Request $request , $id , FileUploader $fileUploader ){

      ...

        $gig = new Gig();
        $form = $this->createForm(GigType::class, $gig);


        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

            $file = $gig->getFlyer();
            $fileName = $fileUploader->upload($file);
            $gig->setFlyer($fileName);

            $em->persist($gig);
            $em->flush();

         ...

    }
```

And here my service declaration in my bundle

```
booking_rooster.uploader:
        class: Booking\RoosterBundle\Uploader\FileUploader
        arguments:
             $targetDir: '%upload_directory%'
```

Comment: Are you using S3.3?  Are you defining the controller as a service?  Doing anything funky with the controller resolver?

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you call a service !

Don't pass it as argument , call it like this :

```
$container->get('booking_rooster.uploader');
```

Comment: Actually, S3.3 supports injecting services directly into action methods.

Comment: thanks for your reply it's working ! do you know why i should not use it as argument ? thanks again for your help

Comment: @Cerad didn't know. Can you explain us the advantages ?

Comment: S3.3+ is making a big commitment to automatically configuring and injecting services.  The existing service locator approach (i.e. $container->get()) is really frowned upon.  Lots and lots of pros and cons for each approach.  I kind of wish the op would have answered the version question.

Comment: @MathieuMourareau I have exact the same problem but cannot get it to work as I don't have the variable `$container`. How can you get it working?